# Debug Silverlight RIA DomainService to DomainContext Code Generation

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, poco, ria, domainservices

I am using Silverlight 4, in Visual Studio 2010.

I have some Domain Services in a project that are being referenced through RIA.

The ones in particular I am concerned with, are domain services that either return, or reference in their parameters, domain-specific (*non-entity*) POCOs.

When the Code Generation occurs for the Silverlight Client project, I am finding that sometimes DomainContext(s) for my DomainServices are being created, and sometimes they are not after some of my code changes.  Likewise, the supporting POCOs are sometimes created and sometimes not.

I feel lost as to what rules are required to get the *DomainContext* code generation to occur correctly and consistently.  At the very least, I would like to see some sort of console output when the code generation to create the DomainContext and support classes is being run so I can determine why some the code generation is not creating what I expect.

Is there any way to debug this process, or get a log of the actions occurring when Visual Studio builds the DomainContext and Silverlight-side classes for POCOs?  At the very least; is there a set of rules that can help me better understand what is going on under the covers?

Comment: Are you doing much with stored procs and complex types?  What are some examples that don't work?

Comment: I had a simple object:
SimpleSelection

With 2 properties.  An Id (int) and a Name (string).  The were not being generated, until I removed the constructor which included both of these properties!!

Comment: did you mark the Id with the [Key] attribute?

Comment: @Derek My comment exactly.  Every class you wish to carry over must be identifiable with a unique value marked [Key].  For cases where this is not important I just add a Key with a GUID generated for the property.

Comment: I did not add the [Key] attribute, and it seems to be working fine after removing the constructor with parameters.  This may have been a change in RIA services SP1 (though I am not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a lot of detailed output when building in Visual Studio 2010 if you set "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to Diagnostic:

```
Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run
    MSBuild project build output verbosity: Diagnostic
```

IIRC you see what the RIA tooling *does* output but it does not tell you what it skips nor why.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/tag/wcf-ria-services/) out, it's dealing with sprocs and complex types but it will give you an idea as to what you need to do to return custom poco's.